# Elephant.io won't emit multiple concurrent requests

Tags: php, node.js, socket.io

I'm using [elephant.io](https://github.com/Wisembly/elephant.io) in PHP side to emit to NodeJS & socket.io server.

PHP code:

```
$server = new Elephant(new Version1X('http://localhost:2020'));

$i = 0;
while($i++ < 10){
    $server->emit('myevent', ['id'=>$i]);
}
```

NodeJS server:

```
var io = require('socket.io')();

io.on('connection', function(socket){

    socket.on('myevent', function(data){
        console.log(data); 
        // Will be executed just one time {id: 1}
    });
});

io.listen(2020);
```

As I have `while($i++ < 10)`, it will be exexuted 10 times but in the server side (NodeJS) it just logs the event one time.

Is that regular? Am I missing something? How to make it enable to emit multiple requests?

Comment: One guess is that you aren't waiting for the ElephantIO connection to be established before immediately trying to `emit()` to it.

Comment: @jfriend00 Isn't that a little unconventional? Logically there were a callback if elephant.io needed waiting to establish connection. I didn't find anything out there which prove elephant.io is async .

Comment: Yeah, I forgot for a moment, you're using PHP.  The [sample code here](https://github.com/Wisembly/elephant.io/blob/master/example/socket.io/1.x/emitter/client.php) shows a `initialize()` method getting called first.